# Copy and Paste to Destination with Variables?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm at a loss with the syntax on this. I've searched and tried probably 20 different ways to write this. How can I fix my syntax or whatever the problem is on the destination of my copy? Here is the code:

```
Dim wksMain As Worksheet, wksStats As Worksheet, i As Long, x As Integer

Set wksMain = Sheets("Main")
Set wksStats = Sheets("Stats")

For x = 1 To 3
   i = 100000000

   wksMain.Range("C3") = i * x
   wksMain.Range("C4") = i * x + i

   wksMain.Calculate

   wksStats.Cells(1, x + 1).Value = wksMain.Cells(8, 4).Value

   wksMain.Range(Cells(16, 6), Cells(37, 6)).Copy _
   Destination:=wksStats.Range(Cells(2, x + 1), Cells(24, x + 1))
Next x
```

**From Comments**

The error that I am getting is `Run-time error '1004' Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet 'failed'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not mentioned what errors are you getting and at what line but I can see a problem with

```
wksMain.Range(Cells(16, 6), Cells(37, 6)).Copy _
Destination:=wksStats.Range(Cells(2, x + 1), Cells(24, x + 1))
```

And that is because you are not fully qualifying your cells object.

Try this (untested)

```
wksMain.Range(wksMain.Cells(16, 6), wksMain.Cells(37, 6)).Copy Destination:= _
wksStats.Range(wksStats.Cells(2, x + 1), wksStats.Cells(24, x + 1))
```

If you do not qualify your cells object then they will always refer to the active sheet.

Comment: Here is the error I was getting . Run-time error '1004' Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet 'failed'. Your solution worked like a charm. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `Here is the error I was getting . Run-time error '1004' Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet 'failed'. Your solution worked like a charm. Thanks for the help. –  Chris2015 23 secs ago` It is always advisable to include this piece of info when you are asking questions. Makes it easier to reply ;)